# How to get particular values from single cell and put into different cells in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to do it for more than 1000 cells, to read the particular data and to put under respective cells using Excel VBA.

Example:

```
Name  Age  No. .. .
abc   14   123454    ------>this from single cell
```

Which contains like `Name: abc,Age: 14, No: 123454`

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-time-by-using-excels-left-right-and-mid-string-functions/

Comment: thanks... but i wanted to get only name , age , No. from single cell here size is not fixed and other information i do not want. how can i do.

Comment: Are there the same number of items in each cell in the same order? If so you could use 'Text to columns' in the data ribbon, using space as the delimiter.

Comment: yes same number of items but I want item1, item3, item5,item6 like that not in sequence order.

Comment: it is like Name:abc, Address: India,....i just want abc, India not Name and Address.

Comment: Well, first step is to break them out using 'Text to columns' as I said. Then, you should just be able to copy the columns you want and rearrange them... It might be helpful if you shared the complete text of one cell, along with what what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start :

```
Sub Split_N_Copy()
Dim InFo()
Dim InfSplit() As String

InFo = ActiveSheet.Cells.UsedRange.Value2
Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

For i = LBound(InFo, 1) To UBound(InFo, 1)
    'Here I put InFo(i,1), "1" if we take the first column
    InfSplit = Split(InFo(i,1), ",")
    For k = LBound(InfSplit) To UBound(InfSplit)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(i + 1, k + 1) = InfSplit(k)
    Next k    
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a function based on `,` for separator sign and `:` for equal sign, that search a range of data that first row contains headers:

```
Function UpdateSheet(allData As String, inRange As Range)

    Dim strData() As String
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim columnName As String, value As String
    Dim cell As Range

    'You need to change this to finding last row like this answer:
    'http://stackoverflow.com/a/15375099/4519059
    lastRow = 2   

    strData = Split(allData, ",")

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        columnName = Trim(Left(strData(i), InStr(1, strData(i), ":") - 1))
        value = Trim(Mid(strData(i), InStr(1, strData(i), ":") + 1))

        For Each cell In inRange
            If cell.Cells(1, 1).Rows(1).Row = 1 Then
                If cell.Cells(1, 1).value Like "*" & columnName & "*" Then
                    inRange.Worksheet.Cells(lastRow, cell.Columns(1).Column).value = value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Function
```

Now you can use that function like this:

```
Sub update()

    Call UpdateSheet("Name: abc,Age: 14, No: 123454", Sheets(1).UsedRange)

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it is working fine...i have done some changes according to my requirements....

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Dim GetData As String
    GetData = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)

    Call UpdateSheet(GetData, Sheets(1).UsedRange, i)

Next

End Sub

Function UpdateSheet(allData As String, inRange As Range, rowno As Integer)

    Dim strData() As String
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim columnName As String, value As String
    Dim cell As Range

    strData = Split(allData, ",")

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)

        Value1 = Trim(Mid(strData(i), InStr(1, strData(i), ":") + 1))

        If Value1 <> "" Then

            columnName = Trim(Left(strData(i), InStr(1, strData(i), ":") - 1))
            value = Trim(Mid(strData(i), InStr(1, strData(i), ":") + 1))

            For Each cell In inRange
                If cell.Cells(1, 1).Rows(1).Row = 1 Then
                    If cell.Cells(1, 1).value Like "*" & columnName & "*" Then
                        inRange.Worksheet.Cells(rowno, cell.Columns(1).Column).value = value
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If

    Next

End Function
```